# Alert formatted as hexadecimal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hex, alert

How do I alert as FF and not 255 with this:

```
var myHex1 = 0xff;  
alert(myHex1);//alerts 255


var myVar = 255;
var myHex2 = myVar.toString(16);
alert(myHex2);//also alerts 255 and not FF
```

Comment: On my machine (Chrome 4) the second alert outputs FF. What is your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was a string I hadn't parsed to an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Your second example works for me exactly how it is.  Are you sure you're alerting the right variable in your test?

Answer (score 0):

And standard compliant approach is:

var x = 0xFF;
window.alert(x.toString(16)); //ff

Regards.